# Applet printing; Applet discards security permission ; Windows7 & Java7

Tags: java, security, printing, applet, liveconnect

Using Java Liveconnect able to access printer through applet from browser, for access rights I've added **`permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "queuePrintJob";`** in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\security\java.policy` file. But still I'm getting the following warning message

[image: SecurityWarningForPrinting]

**Using :** Java Plug-in 10.9.2.05 ; JRE version 1.7.0_09-b05 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

But the same signed applet properly works in xp machine with java7. Even if I check `Always allow....`, it keeps on showing warning again and again. I searched fully in stack overflow but unable to find right fix. Can any one suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: 1) Policy files should not be necessary for a signed applet.  2) It is possible that the root cause is a change in Windows security that is beyond Java's means to alter.

Comment: @AndrewThompson but in xp If I add permission in policy file it grant access and printing works fine without any warning dialog. 2nd point i will check that. thanks.

Comment: Were you ever able to find an answer to this problem?  I created a self-signed applet for testing locally and I am unable to make the access printer prompt go away on my Windows 7 machine.

Comment: @ChadCook I couldn't get you. So you are unable to access printer but don't get any warning ? Problem still exists for me.

Comment: I would love a solution to this. Seems to be a Windows 7 jvm issue. Sort of a big deal if doing any sort of printing. My applet runs through the list of local printers and this pops up once for each printer so you may have to close it 5 times or more.

Comment: @William I couldn't find solution. what I've done is, shared printer in network and printing from server app.

Comment: @vels4j In playing around I found it happens on the latest JVM(1.7.0_17) on all Windows versions. The checkbox is backward. If you don't check it, it won't alert you again until the next time the app runs. It will never remember it longer than a single run though. Also, if you pass the files to print as params at launch, and call print directly from the applet or a button in the applet, it won't display the box ever. It seems to only do it if printing is initialized via a javascript call.